# Why are the values returned as <out of context>, when I run through a loop?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm currently working on a `VBA/Excel`-project.

For this, I was provided by a code, that should work as it is. When testing it, I encountered a problem within a certain loop. If I let the code run through this loop, the values inside and outside of it are set to 0.

If I just comment out the loop (run through the code once), the code works as inteded. When trying to change the loop itself (e.g. renaming the counter or only letting it run through twice, instead of a higher amount), it doesn't work. Hence, I think there is most likely something wrong with the loop, which is marked in Blockquotes in the following code snippet.

```vb
Sub Init_Sheets()
    
    Dim LTP_country() As Variant
    ReDim LTP_country(1 To Le, 1 To 6)
    Dim LTP_country_sorted() As Variant
    ReDim LTP_country_sorted(1 To Le, 1 To 6)
    Dim LCOF_country_sorted() As Variant
    ReDim LCOF_country_sorted(1 To Le, 1 To 6)
    Dim LCOF_WA() As Variant
    ReDim LCOF_WA(1 To La, 1 To 2)
    Dim TSP_WA() As Variant
    ReDim TSP_WA(1 To La, 1 To 2)
    
>For a = 1 To La 'loop over countries**

        For e = 1 To Le 'Loop over classes
            For j = 1 To 6 'loop over columns
                LTP_country(e, j) = LTP_cond(e + (a - 1) * Le, j)
            Next j
        Next e
        LCOF_country_sorted = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sort(LTP_country, 2, 1)
        TSP_country_sorted = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sort(LTP_country, 3, 1)
        For e = 1 To Le 'Loop over classes
        'col 5 is potential allocated, col 6 is potential cummulated sum
            'LCOF sorting and potential allocation-----------
            If LCOF_country_sorted(e, 4) <= m_map - LCOF_country_sorted(e - 1, 6) Then 'if Potential of class <= minimum available potential - cumsum allocated potential
                LCOF_country_sorted(e, 5) = LCOF_country_sorted(e, 4)
            Else
                LCOF_country_sorted(e, 5) = m_map - LCOF_country_sorted(e - 1, 6)
            End If
            LCOF_country_sorted(e, 6) = LCOF_country_sorted(e - 1, 6) + LCOF_country_sorted(e, 5) 'cumsum potenial
    
            'TSP sorting and potential allocation-----------
            If TSP_country_sorted(e, 4) <= m_map - TSP_country_sorted(e - 1, 6) Then 'if Potential of class <= minimum available potential - cumsum allocated potential
                TSP_country_sorted(e, 5) = TSP_country_sorted(e, 4)
            Else
                TSP_country_sorted(e, 5) = m_map - TSP_country_sorted(e - 1, 6)
            End If
            TSP_country_sorted(e, 6) = TSP_country_sorted(e - 1, 6) + TSP_country_sorted(e, 5) 'cumsum potenial
    
        Next e
        If LCOF_country_sorted(9, 6) < m_map Then 'set allocated potential = 0 if the cumsum of all RES potentials is smaller than minimum available potential
            For e = 1 To Le
                LCOF_country_sorted(e, 5) = 0
            Next e
        End If
        If TSP_country_sorted(9, 6) < m_map Then  'set allocated potential = 0 if the cumsum of all RES potentials is smaller than minimum available potential
            For e = 1 To Le
                TSP_country_sorted(e, 5) = 0
            Next e
        End If
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
        LCOF_WA(a, 1) = Left(LCOF_country_sorted(1, 1), 2) 'extract alpha 2 country code from save code
        LCOF_WA(a, 2) = (.SumProduct(.Index(LCOF_country_sorted, 0, 2), .Index(LCOF_country_sorted, 0, 5)) / .Sum(.Index(LCOF_country_sorted, 0, 5))) * 1000 'calculate weighted average of LCOF convert from $/kWh to $/MWh
        
        TSP_WA(a, 1) = Left(TSP_country_sorted(1, 1), 2) 'extract alpha 2 country code from save code
        TSP_WA(a, 2) = (.SumProduct(.Index(TSP_country_sorted, 0, 3), .Index(TSP_country_sorted, 0, 5)) / .Sum(.Index(TSP_country_sorted, 0, 5))) * 1000 'calculate weighted average of LCOF and convert from $/kWh to $/MWh
        End With

>Next a
    
    PrintArray TSP_WA, Geo.[W12]
    PrintArray Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(LCOF_WA, 0, 2), Geo.[Y12]
    
End Sub
```

I hope, that the presented code contains enough information to identify the problem, since some parts were cut out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you used the debugger to check what is going on inside the loop. Use F8 to execute the code step by step and check the content of the variables. Are `Le` and `La` defined somewhere and have the correct values? Do you have the infamous `On Error Resume Next` in your code? Do you use `Option Explicit`?

Comment: "it doesn't work" doesn't tell us much, and this code is likely pretty impenetrable without knowing what's in the Globals it refers to (and with "some parts were cut out").  We have no way of knowing exactly where the "out of context" comes from, or where it's showing up.  Maybe whoever provided this code can address that?